# summing element in a range for all element in an array

Tags: python, arrays, list, data-structures

I have to get the total sum of a range from an array. However the array range needs to move from one element to another. for example if the array is `1,2,3,4,5,6` and if every two element needs to be added , then it should add `1+2` than `2+3` than `3+4` and so on.

I have tried but not getting right approach. I am sure there is a pythonic way of doing this.

here what I have tried

```
data = np.arange(0,20,.3)
for i in range (0,len(data)):
    for j in range(i,len(data)):
        get_range = data[j:5]
        get_add = get_range.sum()
        print("sum:",get_add)
```

I have tried to add every 5 element here.

Comment: `get_range = data[j:j+5]` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a numpyic way to do this. It is more memory- and CPU- effective if your input data is big enougth.

```
import numpy as np

# input array: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
data = np.arange(1, 7)

# cumulative sum: [1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21]
data_cumsum = np.cumsum(data)

# append zero to start: [0, 1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21]
data_cumsum = np.hstack([0, data_cumsum])

# calculate moving sum
window = 2
moving_sum = data_cumsum[window:] - data_cumsum[:-window]

print(moving_sum)
```

Output:

```
[ 3  5  7  9 11]
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use a *list comprehension* which retrieves a `chunks` list.

```
l = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
n = 2
output = [sum(l[i:i + n]) for i in range(0, len(l) - n + 1, 1)]
```

Output

```
[3, 5, 7, 9, 11]
```

Comment: Thanks, I was able to exc it with pseudo code, but not able to in python

Comment: Do you mean you couldn't run it for your data?

Comment: For this solution, should the range function not be `range(0, len(l) - n, n - 1)` instead?

Comment: I don't think you need step argument for this usecase

Answer (score 1):

A minor change will solve the problem

```
data = np.arange(0,10)

for j in range(0,len(data)-1):
    get_range = data[j:j+2] #changed from j to j+2
    get_add = get_range.sum()
    print("sum:",get_add)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
('sum:', 1)
('sum:', 3)
('sum:', 5)
('sum:', 7)
('sum:', 9)
('sum:', 11)
('sum:', 13)
('sum:', 15)
('sum:', 17)
```

You can easily condense above steps to form a list comprehension giving the same results with same complexity

```
[sum(data[j:j+2]) for j in range(0,len(data)-1)]
```

Another fancy approach could be using `sliding_window` function

```
from toolz.itertoolz import sliding_window
map(sum,list(sliding_window(2,list(range(0,10)))))
```

**Output**

```
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17]
```